# Adding semantics using prolog

Tags: parsing, prolog

to compile a syntax portion of a language we need to parse syntactically and lexiqually
then a step that is not trivial: adding semantic

what I do is to use DCG with some predicates in prolog for the first two step, but now I want to know  how it done for the semantic ?
how I consider this task?
separate to the parser or mix it with them?...

*EDIT :*

Usually, a semantic of simple expression with DCG be written as;

```
expr (Z) -> term(X) "+", expr(Y), {Z is X + Y}.
```

but if the language is based on logical formulas such as B Method , problem become more complicated,
and what I need is  some tips to overcome this problem

sorry about the wrong expressions

*I am very appreciated to your opinions*

Comment: Really not very clear what you are asking here.

Comment: I think @Boris means that semantics and syntax are both very broad categories, and they are often interchangeable. After all, (pure) Prolog is a term rewrite language, that is, purely syntactical. Anyway, my opinion is that you should add arguments as needed by the computation to your DCG, *if* you can carry them on *without* side effects.

Comment: @CapelliC what I think :
 suppose That I Have exp_invariant = "var ∈ Set" and explicitly enumerate set (Set = [Set1, Set2]=Vals)
so I get var_sets_db (var, Set, Vals)